# T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING error that I cannot resolve

Tags: php, syntax-error

This code:

```
    $current_user = get_currentuseinfo();
foreach ($alleds as $ed) {
    $checked = (in_array($ed->ID,(array)$currenteds)) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
    $disabled = (!current_user_can('administrator') && $current_user->ID !== $ed->ID) ? ' disabled="disabled" : '';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="currenteds[]" value="' . $ed->ID . '"' .$checked . '" '.$disabled.' /><label for="ratings[]">'.$ed->user_nicename.'</label>';
}
```

Is giving me this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING
```

Now, I have been trying to wrap my head into why I am receiving this error but I cannot figure it out. The issue may be on the `echo` line. Do you know what the issue is and how I fix it?

Comment: You could have resolved this very simply using the age-old technique known as _counting_. Syntax highlighting also shows you exactly where the problem is. Also this would have been easier for you to spot if you didn't try to cram as much code as possible into each individual line. Spread your code out a bit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing a *closing single quote*:

```
$disabled = (!current_user_can('administrator') && $current_user->ID !== $ed->ID) ? ' disabled="disabled" : '';
```

should be:

```
$disabled = (!current_user_can('administrator') && $current_user->ID !== $ed->ID) ? ' disabled="disabled"' : '';
```

Look at the syntax highlighting in your question, or your editor, and it should pop out for you.

Comment: Wow... Would love to see the explanation for a down vote on this answer.

Comment: Me too. I'd also like to see the explanation for an upvote on the question. Voting patterns are _bizarre_ nowadays.